# How to hide the WorkSpace Link on hudson/jenkins web page?

Tags: hudson, jenkins

Because source code can not be accessed by all users, I want to remove the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the "Manage Jenkins [Hudson]" > "Configure System" page, "Enable Security".

Add the user or group you want to limit, and in the checkboxes, uncheck **Workspace** under Job.

This will prevent that user or group from being able to read the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

Note that in Jenkins v1.504 the user security is no longer under the configuration tab it is in its own 'Global Security' tab.

Goto: "Manage Jenkins [Hudson]" > "Configure Global Security" > Check "Enable Security"

Answer (score 2):

Note that in Jenkins v2.319, the "Enable Security" is removed, and the config is under the "Authorization".

Goto: "Manage Jenkins [Hudson]" > "Configure Global Security" > "Authorization"